# GCC converts reference to temporary when doing static_cast to void pointer reference

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, static-cast

***GCC*** produces warning when compiling the following code:

```
void* const & cast(int* const &ptr)
{
    return static_cast<void* const &>(ptr);
}
```

The warning is *"returning reference to temporary"* ([coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/367b3940124d1fb9)).

***Clang*** compiles the code without warnings ([coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1921c77099ae059)).

Which compiler is right? And why is reference converted to temporary?

Also note that changing `static_cast` to `reinterpret_cast` fixes the warning ([coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0354f1c30c58610d)).

Comment: Handy reading: [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002)

Comment: For this function _not_ to return a reference to a temporary, one would need to count on the parameter being _reinterpreted_.  That would have to be the intention of the author.

Comment: Note: A lack of a warning doesn't necessarily mean code will work. the C++ Standard is full of "No diagnostic required"s.

Comment: "converts reference to temporary" technically it doesn't, because an expression cannot have a reference type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang 12 [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oohKzj43K) gives me a similar warning. The one you linked to is probably outdated.

The code is broken, you return a dangling reference.

Unlike `reinterpret_cast`, the `static_cast` will refuse to reinterpret the reference. Instead it will construct a temporary of type `void *`<sup>1</sup> from the original pointer, and form a reference to it (which is allowed, since the reference is `const`).

Note that performing a `reinterpret_cast` instead, and then reading/writing to the resulting reference, violates strict aliasing and causes undefined behavior.

---

<sup>1</sup> I *think* it's a `void *` instead of `void *const` because of [`[expr.type]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-2).